# vscode css code definitions

Tags: visual-studio-code

I used a CSS class in HTML, but this class is not defined yet

[image: Image Link "class in HTML"]

Then I tried to define this class in CSS. However, vscode cannot suggest me an already existing class.

[image: Image Link "in CSS"]

I'm new in vs code - please suggest me extension for this (I tried a lot of extensions but never found a working)

**Update:**

In an Atom it works, please check:
in HTML:
[in HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NVswO.png)
And in CSS
[in CSS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LVeDI.png)

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing things here. CSS class completion works the other way around. You define the class in your CSS and then vscode will offer that as candidate when you write your HTML tag and assign it a class.

Comment: ok, but in an atom it works, please check: HTML - https://ibb.co/jmk7OS and CSS - https://ibb.co/j4oSOS

Comment: I guess that's this poor man's code completion. Every word that was written once, is provided as completion in a file, if there's no specific completion provider for that file type. This also works in vscode.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you declare the class name first in your css/scss file, then in an html file you can get intellisense for those class names with the extension [class completion in html](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Zignd.html-css-class-completion).